# Does Firebird Database support Schema? If so, how can I create a schema in Firebird DB through ISQL?

Tags: sql, schema, firebird, jaybird

Does Firebird Database support Schema? If so, how can I create a schema in Firebird DB through ISQL? Please help me to create schemas in Firebird DB. I have tried to retrieve schema using

```
AbstractDatabaseMetaData.getSchemas()
```

But it is always retrieving empty resultset. Can anyone please help me in retrieving schemas? At least SYSTEM schema when there is no schema.

Comment: Why do you think Jaybird should return `SYSTEM` when there is no schema?

Answer (score 6):

Firebird currently doesn't have schemas, and therefor Jaybird doesn't return any. This complies with the JDBC specification, which [says](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html):

> If a given form of metadata is not available, an empty `ResultSet` will be returned.

Note that Firebird does have a `CREATE SCHEMA`, but that is simply an alias for `CREATE DATABASE`.

Answer (score 1):

No, schema not supported, but you can create many databases files. [Here](http://www.firebirdsql.org/manual/qsg10-creating.html) manual for create database with Firebird tool. Also you can create database with IBExpert or similar tool.
Also, you can create sql-cript for automate it:

```
$ isql -q -i create-db.sql
```

Also you can run it from java code.

```
--Contents of create-db.sql
CREATE DATABASE '/my/path/my-db.fdb' page_size 8192 USER 'SYSDBA' PASSWORD 'masterkey';
CREATE EXCEPTION EX_SOME_EXCEPTION 'Some extension message';
CREATE TABLE ROOMS (
 ID integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
 Number char(10),
 Name char(100),
 Network char(100),
 Memo char(100)
);

CREATE GENERATOR ROOMS_IDGEN;
SET TERM !! ;
CREATE TRIGGER ON_ROOMS_INS FOR ROOMS BEFORE INSERT AS
BEGIN
 IF (NEW.ID IS NULL) THEN NEW.ID=GEN_ID(ROOMS_IDGEN, 1);
END !!
SET TERM ; !!
....
```

Comment: A database is not exactly the same thing as a schema (in JDBC terms a "database" is usually mapped to a "catalog") - but probably the closest thing you can get with Firebird